# Windows 10 SSH server installation does not create required services

Tags: powershell, windows-10, openssh

I am trying to install Open-SSH on my Windows 10 pc in order to connect to it from my linux machine with ssh. I am following [this tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/using-the-openssh-beta-in-windows-10-fall-creators-update-and-windows-server-1709/), but as soon as I have to run something like `Start-Service ssh-agent`, it says that the service doesn't exist. Another thing that doesn't work is `Install-Module -Force OpenSSHUtils`, and it says that `the signature of the file 'OpenSSHUtils.psd1' is not valid.` I have tried many other tutorials, uninstalling everything before each one, and none of them are working. Is there any way to install these things manually? Am I missing an important step of the installation?

Comment: If you don't install the module properly then it's likely nothing is going to work. What is the result if you run the following command? Get-ExecutionPolicy. Also which method did you use to install? Powershell/DISM/Windows Features?

Comment: @Scepticalist
When I run that command it says Unrestricted. (I am using Administrator privileges)
I have tried all three of those methods, but I feel like I got the furthest using Powershell

Comment: This question has nothing to do with a coding problem in Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do know you can install SSH directly in Windows 10 by using Add Feature option, correct? No need to download an external module/tool unless the builtin one does not provide all you are after.

> [Installation of OpenSSH For Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

```
# Install the OpenSSH Client
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

# Install the OpenSSH Server
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Using the GUI

> [How to Enable and Use Windows 10’s New Built-in SSH Commands](https://www.howtogeek.com/336775/how-to-enable-and-use-windows-10s-built-in-ssh-commands)

Yet, if you do decide to use external stuff, then, Always test destructive (CUD = Create, Update, delete) code before true implementation.

```
Find-Module -Name 'OpenSSHUtils' -Verbose

<#
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: The -Repository parameter was not specified.  PowerShellGet will use all of the registered repositories.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='OpenSSHUtils'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'OpenSSHUtils'.

Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                                                           
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                                                           
1.0.0.1              OpenSSHUtils                        PSGallery            Configure OpenSSH for Windows related security settings like file owner and permissions. 
#>


Find-Module -Name 'OpenSSHUtils' -Verbose | 
Save-Module -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" -Verbose -WhatIf
<#
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: The -Repository parameter was not specified.  PowerShellGet will use all of the registered repositories.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='OpenSSHUtils'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'OpenSSHUtils'.
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'PSGallery', Location = 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'; IsTrusted = 'False'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Using the specified source names : 'PSGallery'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='OpenSSHUtils'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'OpenSSHUtils'.
What if: Performing the operation "Save Package" on target "'OpenSSHUtils' to location 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'".
#>

Install-Module -Name 'OpenSSHUtils' -Verbose -WhatIf

<#
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: The -Repository parameter was not specified.  PowerShellGet will use all of the registered repositories.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Searching repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='OpenSSHUtils'' for ''.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'OpenSSHUtils'.
What if: Performing the operation "Install-Module" on target "Version '1.0.0.1' of module 'OpenSSHUtils'".
#>
```

Comment: I followed all of the commands, but `Install-Module -Name 'OpenSSHUtils' -Verbose gives this error: 
`The module 'OpenSSHUtils' cannot be installed or updated because the authenticode
signature of the file 'OpenSSHUtils.psd1' is not valid.`
Also, I followed microsoft's tutorial and when it says to do this:
`Start-Service sshd
# OPTIONAL but recommended:
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'`
it doesn't do anything because the service doesn't exist. There aren't any services even related to ssh or sshd.

Comment: You can download the module manually from here: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OpenSSHUtils/1.0.0.1. Open the NuPkg with winzip or similar and copy the folder to your modules folder. Then see if Import-module works.